# How do I compare dates and filter accordingly on tabulator js?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using tabulator js to view my data as reports. I want to filter it according to two dates (start and end). Also, the "date" data is not a field in my table. I've tried several methods to try to compare my data to the start and end dates i have in the calendar and none have worked so far. Any help would be appreciated! This is how I'm retrieving the dates from the calendar (which work btw) and adjusting their format to MM/DD/YYYY as I have the dates in the data.

```
let date1 = new Date(startD._d);
    startD._d = ((date1.getMonth() > 8) ? (date1.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date1.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date1.getDate() > 9) ? date1.getDate() : ('0' + date1.getDate())) + '/' + date1.getFullYear()
    let date2 = new Date(endD._d);
    endD._d =((date2.getMonth() > 8) ? (date2.getMonth() + 1) : ('0' + (date2.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((date2.getDate() > 9) ? date2.getDate() : ('0' + date2.getDate())) + '/' + date2.getFullYear()
```

And this is was my last trial of trying to compare the retrieved dates to dates in my data:

```
function updateDate(){
        $("#example-table").tabulator("addFilter", [
            {field:"date", type:">=", value:startD._d},//returns values greater than or equal to start date
            {field:"date", type:"<=", value:endD._d},//returns values less than or equal to end date 
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Please include table constructor above. Also not sure I understand 'the "date" data is not a field in my table' when you have '{field:"date", type:">=", value:startD._d}'?

Comment: Also do you have moment.js installed?

Comment: the  '{field:"date", type:">=", value:startD._d}' is just for comparison; i.e. it was one way to retreive the date from my dataset and compare it the start date i retrieved from the calendar (startD._d). What i mean is in my table the field 'date' is not included. It's in my dataset but i do not want to view it in my table. And, yes i do have moment.js installed but that's not the issue

Comment: this is just part of my code of course i have a table constructor.

Comment: If you want to filter on 'date' it will need to be part of your table. It could be a hidden ```visible: false```, but it will need to be there. The exception being AJAX filtering where you pass the filters back to whatever is  providing the data and filter there.  Right now you doing string comparisons and that is not going to work like you want. You will need to do ```Date``` comparisons and moment,js will make that easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using a numeric filter on a string so it is doing a simple string comparison rather than a date comparison.

Tabulator will not automatically assume that a text string is a date. You would need to use a custom filter, that uses either the built in JavaScript Date object or a library like moment *(probably best as it handles the man different formats for dates)* to compare two dates and check that they are less than the value

```
//custom filter for date of birth column
function dateFilter(data, value){
    //data - the data for the row being filtered
    //value- params object passed to the filter

    return moment(data.dob, "DD/MM/YYYY").diff(moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY")) > 0;
}

//set filter
table.setFilter(dateFilter, "14/04/1983");
```

For full details checkout the [Custom Filter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/filter#func-custom)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried for I mean 100 times to test date filter on [Tabulator site](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.1?#filter) and the only thing I can say is: date filter on Tabulator doesn't work correctly!

I tried filters on `Date of birth` column and the result is:

- Equality comparer works:

[image]

- Like comparer works:

[image]

- Less or equal comparer doesn't work:

Should returns

[image]

But returns

[image]

- Greater or equal comparer doesn't work:

Should returns

[image]

But returns

[image]

You note the same thing? What I'm doing wrong? Can you confirm this? I know this is not an answer but as you can see maybe there are some problems with library.

Comment: Yes, I saw the same exact problem! maybe a glitch in the library?

Comment: Could be, I don't know... Maybe you could open a bug.

Comment: It is a generic setup that filters on string values.  It would need a custom filter that actually worked with dates.